# Deploy SignalR HelloWorld in Servers, one is good, another doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just deployed SingalR samples on servers (Using jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js), referring to 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

On QA Server works good, i can boardcast message correctly.
But in UAT server, always showing error when doing:

```
var chat = $.connection.chat;
```

Throwing chat unidentified error, 
i just checked two servers, all winServer2008R2, IIS7.5, 
Same app pool settings, .Net framework 4 installed.

Not sure what to do more to figure out what happened to my UAT Server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue.
in QA, it's Win2008R2 SP1, but in UAT, it's Win2008R2.
And after install this patch
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368/

it works!
It's **An update is available that enables certain IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period.**

Got help from my USA workmate, really thanks to him.